# Sort a java stream with a non-total ordering criteria.

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream, partial-ordering

I am trying to create a method that sorts a List by making:

```
private List<Processor> getByPriority(){                        
    return processors.stream().sorted( new ProcessorComparator() ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
}
```

But I read in the [Comprator javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that compare to needs to be a total ordering relation. That is, no two comparator may have the same priority unless they are equal. This might not be the case.

I was trying this simple comparator:

```
public class ProcessorComparator implements Comparator<TTYMessageProcessor<?>>{

    @Override
    public int compare( Processor processor1 , Processor processor2 ) {         
        return processor1.getPriority() - processor2.getPriority();
    }       
}
```

Of course I could make the Processor Comparable but I would like to avoid modifications to all the Proccessors. Isn't there any way to sort them with streams? As alternatives I could write my own method or create a more complex comparator but I am surprised of the lack of a more elegant solution.

Comment: if you don't care about the ordering of processors of equal priority, that's a perfectly fine comparator as the "equality" in this case is defined as the equality of processor priority, not the processors themselves

Comment: It won't be coherent with the equals method according to javadoc. But I am not really sure of the consecuences. I just want to make sure that the stream does not consider it already existing and delete it. On the other hand I do not mind at all if processors with the same ordering gets sorted randomly. One day Pc(p=2) appears before  Pb(p=2) and viceversa.  Your phrase "equality of process priority vs equality of objects was enlighting"

Comment: I'd you're using Java 8, this is way more complicated than it needs to be: use `Comparator.comparingInt(Processor::getPriority)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-) the elements of the original stream are preserved:

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream, sorted according to the provided Comparator.

No elements will be evicted, deleted or duplicated. The same elements come out of the sort as go in, just re-ordered.

Edit: the docs also state for [Comparator.compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-)

> It is generally the case, **but not strictly required** that (compare(x,
>   y)==0) == (x.equals(y)). Generally speaking, any comparator that
>   violates this condition should clearly indicate this fact. The
>   recommended language is "Note: this comparator imposes orderings that
>   are inconsistent with equals."

This may introduce confusion about `equals` when used in maps or sets:

> Caution should be exercised when using a comparator capable of
>   imposing an ordering inconsistent with equals to order a sorted set
>   (or sorted map). Suppose a sorted set (or sorted map) with an explicit
>   comparator c is used with elements (or keys) drawn from a set S. If
>   the ordering imposed by c on S is inconsistent with equals, the sorted
>   set (or sorted map) will behave "strangely." In particular the sorted
>   set (or sorted map) will violate the general contract for set (or
>   map), which is defined in terms of equals.

The confusion is lifted if you think about `Comparator` as an abstraction of the key-value pair: you wouldn't expect two pairs to be equal in case their keys were equal. It just means that some property of those values (i.e. their keys) is considered alike. If you wanted an object to be `Comparable` in a manner consistent with `equals` best implement the equally named interface [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Comment: @borjab what you've added doesn't apply at all to sorting a list. For sets and maps look at it this way: comparator abstracts the concept of having a key-value pair where you sort pairs for their key, never is there an assumption that the pair equals another if their keys compare equals. In fact in this sense I strongly disagree with the actual documentation wording choice *It is generally the case...*, it's generally **not** the case, otherwise you'd implement `Comparable.compareTo` not an external `Comparator`...